# JPA order without class

Tags: java, jpa

Is possible to create Order without class? I get form view(which is extjs) a request with parameter `sort = [{property:name,direction:ASC}]`. Standart way of creation is like:

```
    criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyUser> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyUser.class);
    Root<PeryklesUser> routeRoot = query.from(MyUser.class);
    query.select(routeRoot);
    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList();
    orderList.add(criteriaBuilder.desc(routeRoot.get("name")));
```

Is it possible to create Order without calling root made from entity class?
In orderby annotation u can add `@Orderby("name,asc")` but with `creiteriaBuilder` can't.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Metamodel API so that you do not have to create root. YOu can simpy acces `name` property using `PeryklesUser_.name` instead of `routeRoot.get("name")`

But honestly I do not mind creating a root and then accessign properties instead of using metamodel api.